# Search Bar only works in console and not in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uisearchbar

My Search Bar works in console but in the simulator doesn't work and i don't know why.
I have tried with many codes but nothing works. I'm looking for restaurant names in my tableview but when i type nothing happen, everything stays equal in the simulator.

This is my code:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    if([searchText length] == 0){
        [jsonObject2 removeAllObjects];
        [jsonObject2 addObjectsFromArray:jsonObject];
    }else{
        [jsonObject2 removeAllObjects];

        for(NSDictionary *dictionary in jsonObject)
        {
            NSObject *ob = [dictionary objectForKey:@"nombres"];
            if([ob isKindOfClass: [NSString class]])
            {
                NSString*string=[ob description];
                NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

                if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                    [jsonObject2 addObject:ob];
                    NSLog(@"%@",jsonObject2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    [myTableView reloadData];
}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)asearchBar{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: use [jsonObject2 retain]; below the NSLog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be two reasons for this issue

1. You are using `jsonObject` as your data source of table view. If so use `jsonObject2`.
2. If first case is wrong then may be you should log your `jsonObject2` after all search component are added in that. And fix that in case it doesn't string objects in it.

Comment: Then you can accept this answer as well, by clicking on tick mark next to the answer, (it's your stackoverflow, responsibility ;) :D ).

Answer (score 0):

First check `UITableView` and `UISearchBar` are add properly or not ??? ... and then Take Two `NSMutableArray` and **add one array to  another array** in `ViewDidLoad` method such like,

```
self.listOfTemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // array no - 1
self.ItemOfMainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"YorArrayList", nil]; // array no - 2 

[self.listOfTemArray addObjectsFromArray:self.ItemOfMainArray]; // add 2array to 1 array
```

**And Write following Methos of code**

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
        NSString *name = @"";
        NSString *firstLetter = @"";

    if (self.listOfTemArray.count > 0)
         [self.listOfTemArray removeAllObjects];

        if ([searchText length] > 0)
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < [self.ItemOfMainArray count] ; i = i+1)
                {
                        name = [self.ItemOfMainArray objectAtIndex:i];

                        if (name.length >= searchText.length)
                        {
                                firstLetter = [name substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
                                //NSLog(@"%@",firstLetter);

                                if( [firstLetter caseInsensitiveCompare:searchText] == NSOrderedSame )
                                {
                                    // strings are equal except for possibly case
                                    [self.listOfTemArray addObject: [self.ItemOfMainArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                                    NSLog(@"=========> %@",self.listOfTemArray);
                                }
                         }
                 }
         }
         else
         {
             [self.listOfTemArray addObjectsFromArray:self.ItemOfMainArray ];
         }

        [self.tblView reloadData];
}
```

And Write in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Foobar"];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Foobar"];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

        cell.textLabel.text = [self.listOfTemArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

This code might helpful for you...thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem and i add this code to search textDidChange method:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
if([searchText length] == 0){
    [jsonObject2 removeAllObjects];
    [jsonObject2 addObjectsFromArray:jsonObject];
    //NSLog(@"%@",jsonObject2);
}else{
    [jsonObject2 removeAllObjects];
    for(NSDictionary *dictionary in jsonObject)
    {
        NSString*string=[dictionary objectForKey:@"nombres"];
            NSRange range=[string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                [jsonObject2 addObject:dictionary];
                NSLog(@"%@",jsonObject2);
        }
    }
}
[myTableView reloadData];  
}
```